# Merge CSV Files (Without Duplicates) in Batch

Tags: csv, batch-file, windows-7, merge, command-prompt

I want to merge two similar CSV files using batch. I have found a file that was working perfectly and now is not. This may have been due to renaming the CSV files that were used.

I want what is demonstrated below:

File 1:

```
name1,group1,data1
name2,group2,data2
name3,group3,data3
```

File 2:

```
name1,group1,data1,time1
name2,group2,data2,time2
```

Merged file:

```
name1,group1,data1,time1
name2,group2,data2,time2
name3,group3,data3
```

(Note that the fourth column was not filled in by name3 and was subsequently not on file 2.)

The following code was modified from: http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/MS_DOS/Q_27694997.html.

```
@echo off

set "tmpfile=%temp%\importlist.tmp"
set "csvfile=importlist.csv"
copy nul "%tmpfile%" >nul

echo.
echo Processing all CSV files...
set "header="
for %%a in (%1) do (
    if not "%%a"=="%csvfile%" (
        set /p =Processing %%a...<nul
        for /f "tokens=1* usebackq delims=," %%b in ("%%a") do (
            if /i "%%b"=="Keyword" (
                if not defined header (
                    set /p =Found header...<nul
                    set "header=%%b,%%c"
                )
            ) else (
                title [%%a] - %%b,%%c
                findstr /b /c:"%%b" /i "%tmpfile%">nul || echo %%b,%%c>>"%tmpfile%"
            )
        )
        echo OK
    )
)
echo Finished processing all CSV files

echo.
echo Creating %csvfile%
echo %header%>"%csvfile%"

set /p =Sorting data...<nul
sort "%tmpfile%">>"%csvfile%"
echo OK
del "%tmpfile%"

echo Finished!
title Command Prompt
exit /b
```

The problem is that when executed it just creates a sorted CSV with all the data from the first file and not the second.

I have attempted to get it working by putting quotation marks around the parameter (%1 - "directory*.csv") to no avail.

Comment: What the `%1` and `%2` mean? Please [edit] your question and provide a calling line example(s), e.g. `myscript.bat "File 1" "File 2"` or `myscript.bat "c:\myfiles\File 1" "c:\myfiles\File 2"` or  `myscript.bat File1 File2` etc...

Comment: Based on the ExpertsExchange question, it looks like `%1` is _supposed_ to be `*.csv`, which would explain the `for` loop. It would also explain why there's no `%2` anywhere in the script, since you're not supposed to call it like `script.bat file1.csv file2.csv file2.csv`.

Comment: Apologies, I've edited it now.
The command line would be merge.bat "directory\*.csv"

Comment: Sorry, I have limited access only to Experts-Exchange... So, I didn't bother about clicking it, not yet. Mazy by OP's reference to `%2`. @SomethingDark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try this

```
@echo off &setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file1.csv) do set "@%%~a=7"
for /f "tokens=1-4delims=," %%a in (file2.csv) do (
    set "lx1=@%%~a,%%~b,%%~c"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if defined !lx1! (
        endlocal
        set "@%%~a,%%~b,%%~c="
    ) else (
        endlocal
    )
    set "@%%~a,%%~b,%%~c,%%~d=4"
)
(for /f "delims==@" %%a in ('set @') do echo %%~a)>merge.csv
type merge.csv
```

It doesn't work, if you have `=` or `@` in your data.

Comment: That did it! Even with "%1" swapping as file1.csv and "%2" swapping as file2.csv. I hope this batch file won't break like the other one!